# Mongo Connection issue with error "state should be: open"

Tags: java, mongodb, akka

I am running an event in Akka actor system, where we run multiple actors to query mongo db and retrieve data. Each actor queries for 1000 documents (each document's size is 9kb)

When running an event that is required to fire 14 actors to query for Mongo DB to retrieve 13000 documents.Once I experienced below exception, not sure why? Have anyone experienced this before?

```
2020-04-14 19:17:28,818 [erp-writer-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-378] ERROR c.a.s.c.m.GlobalContextMongoClientService- 76cd7a80-83ef-4389-885a-be9caed77449 - Exception occured while reading data from cursor
java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
 at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:70)
 at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:84)
 at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:86)
 at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:203)
 at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:103)
 at com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46)
 at com.xyz.smartconnect.commons.mongoclient.GlobalContextMongoClientService.findWorkers(GlobalContextMongoClientService.java:145)
 at com.xyz.smartconnect.actors.QueryWorkersActor.lambda$createReceive$0(QueryWorkersActor.java:40)
 at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
 at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
 at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
 at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
 at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
 at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:513)
 at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:132)
 at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:519)
 at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:488)
 at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
 at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
 at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
 at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
 at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
 at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
 at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
 Suppressed: java.lang. IllegalStateException: state should be: open
  at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:70)
  at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:84)
  at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:86)
  at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.killCursor(QueryBatchCursor.java:261)
  at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.close(QueryBatchCursor.java:147)
  at com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.close(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:41)
  at com.xyz.smartconnect.commons.mongoclient.GlobalContextMongoClientService.findWorkers(GlobalContextMongoClientService.java:149)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running multiple tests and analyzing the logs carefully, I found the root cause. Below are the details.

While the application is using cursor to query data from mongoDb, connection has been released/closed. 'State should be : open' is complaining about a released connection.

In my case, my application experienced OutOfMemory, which caused disposing beans and releasing connections. Here is timeline of log events for this issue.

Since this is a memory issue for my case, fixing memory issue will fix below exception for me.

```
2020-04-19 12:57:32,981 [xyz-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-72] ERROR a.a.ActorSystemImpl-  - 413f9298-ca92-4744-913b-59934e4ce831 - exception on LARS’ timer thread
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:269)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-19 12:57:43,649 [Thread-19] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor-  -  - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2020-04-19 12:58:13,483 [Thread-19] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter-  -  - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2020-04-19 12:58:45,186 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  c.a.s.ApplicationContextListener-  -  - >>>>>>>>> Disposing beans
2020-04-19 12:59:00,182 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  c.a.s.c.SpringBeanDisposer-  -  - Mongo connections are released.
2020-04-19 12:59:09,591 [xyz-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-73] ERROR c.a.s.c.m.GlobalContextMongoClientService-  - 413f9298-ca92-4744-913b-59934e4ce831 - Exception occured while reading data from cursor
java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getDescription(DefaultServer.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getServerDescription(ClusterBinding.java:81)
    at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.initFromCommandResult(QueryBatchCursor.java:251)
    at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:207)
    at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:103)
    at com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46)
```